# Basic pom.xml file for Scala Maven projects

Tags: scala, maven

Can someone recommend a basic `pom.xml` file for a Scala project on Maven? So far, none of the options I get from `mvn archetype:generate` seems to be as basic as I would like. I want only the dependencies and plugins that are absolutely required to run a Scala jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scala-maven-plugin` is the only friend you need, basically add this plugin to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You might be interested in adding some `configuration` or `execution` parts to it, but you can read more about it on their website: http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/

Comment: Adding to above answer, here is a reference to how to construct a POM file from scratch: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html